# Update Objects LIst<T> With Multiple Items

Tags: c#, list

I can update a List using "single line" updates, but I'd like to update multiple items on a single line, similar to the way the List is initialized.

Here is my code:

```
 public class Players
{
    public int id;
    public string Rank = "";
    public string PlayerName = "";
    public string LName = "";
    public string FName = "";
    public string Team = "";
}


List<Players> newList = new List<Players>();

        newList.Add(new Players() { id = 111, PlayerName = "Alpha" });
        newList.Add(new Players() { id = 222, PlayerName = "Beta" });
        newList.Add(new Players() { id = 333, PlayerName = "Gamma" });

        newList[0].FName = "Joe";
        newList[0].LName = "Smith";
        newList[0].Team = "Yankees";

      //  newList[1] ={ FName="Babe" , Lname="Ruth", Team="Boston"};


        foreach(var item in newList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.id+"  "+item.PlayerName+" "+item.FName+"  "+item.LName+" "+item.Team);
        }
```

I want to use something like below to update the list object with multiple items with one line. But this line throws and exception "FName does not exist in current context"

This is the error line     //  newList[1] ={ FName="Babe" , Lname="Ruth", Team="Boston"};

How do I create/format the correct way to update a List object?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not an assignment. Why do you want *one* line for those updates? And if one line is so important, why not add a method to `Player` to update itself  from another instance?

Comment: BTW `Players` has no properties which is going to cause problems. Properties aren't just access methods, they're part of an object's interface. Fields, even public fields, are implementation details. Serializes and ORMs will serialize properties by default while ignoring fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set those three properties with a one liner, why not implementing a method in the Player class?

```
public class Player {

    //...

    public void SetProperties(string Fname, string Lname, string team)
    {
        FName = fName,
        LName = lName,
        Team = team
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
var newList = new List<Player>();
//...
newList[0].SetProperties("Babe", "Ruth", "Boston");
```

Edit: @godot suggested that is better to have a method to update just some properties of the Player object. A way to achieve this goal is reflection and anonymous types.
I propose a refactoring of the SetProperties method:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }

    public void SetProperties(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyToUpdate = this.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            if(propertyToUpdate != null) propertyToUpdate.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(obj));
        }
    }
```

By implementing this method you can update your list object like this:

```
newList[0].SetProperties( new { FName = "Babe", LName = "Ruth", Team = "Boston" } );
```

Comment: it would be better to take in mind situation when SetProperties method is being called to change some properties and not all of them

Comment: Marco, it works with the following changes.public void SetProperties(string fName, string lName, string team)
        {
            FName = fName;
            LName = lName;
            Team = team;
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can create/format the entire player by creating a new player and overwriting everything.

```
newList[1] = new Players() { FName="Babe" , Lname="Ruth", Team="Boston"};
```

Comment: and what if here is needed to update object partially?

Comment: @godot, Then I would use Marco's solution.  I just wanted to add the case for replacing the whole thing to this question.